# How to deserialize nested Firebase database in Java with Map<String, Obect> or List <object> class?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my simple primary Firebase data.

```
{
  "elephant" : {
    "color" : "gray",
    "lifespan" : 48,
    "status" : "endangered"
  }
}
```

In my android project I made this class to represent this data

```
public class elephant{
    private String color;
    private int lifespan;
    private String status;

    // Constructors
    public elephant(){
    }

    public elephant(String color, int lifespan, String status) { . . . }

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getColor() { return color; }

    public void setColor(String color) { this.color = color; }

    public int getLifespan() { return lifespan; }

    public void setLifespan(int lifespan) { this.lifespan = lifespan; }

    public String getStatus() { return status; }

    public void setStatus(String status) { this.status = status; }
}
```

That way I can call getValue(elephant.class) method to retrieve this data.

```
Elephant ele = datasnapshot.getValue(elephant.class);
```

It works.

Now I'm adding one nested node in my project.

```
{
  "elephant" : {
    "color" : "gray",
    "lifespan" : 48,
    "status" : "endangered",
    "dimension" : {
      "height" : 270,
      "length" : 607
    }
  }
}
```

[image: database Image]

I've created a new class called Dimension.java in my project:

```
public class Dimension {
    private int length, height;

    // Constructors
    public Dimension() { }

    public Dimension(int length, int height) { . . . }

    // Public getters and setters
    public int getLength() {return length;}

    public void setLength(int length) {this.length = length;}

    public int getHeight() {return height;}

    public void setHeight(int height) {this.height = height;}
}
```

And I modified my elephant.java to include this variable/object:

```
private Dimension dimension;
```

and proper constructor, getters and setters for it.

and my previous method still works. It returns the proper java representation for the whole datasnapshot.

```
Elephant ele = datasnapshot.getValue(elephant.class);
```

and, If I get a datasnapshot at DatabaseRef.child('dimension') I can pass the dimension.class to getValue() method to get proper data:

```
Dimension data = datasnapshot.getValue(dimension.class);
```

Thus these multipurpose classes are pretty convenient to me.

Now, I know, Firebase data is supposed to be normalized/flattened. But for experiments sake let's say I've added some data with pushID.

```
{
  "elephant" : {
    "color" : "gray",
    "status" : "endangered",
    "lifespan" : 48,
    "dimension" : {
      "height" : 270,
      "length" : 607
    },
    "population" : {
      "-KTcpw_SsMb55qLc6Xme" : {
        "count" : 210,
        "location" : "Bangladesh"
      },
      "-KTcq6YeB3kX3h9F9xPU" : {
        "count" : 428,
        "location" : "Bhutan"
      },
      "-KTcqDySLBAFtCuUc3R4" : {...},
      "-KTcqMyy4GULKo6FqPEM" : {...},
      "-KTcqWwtli672ROpry8_" : {...},
      "-KTcqhnBb6dTN1mA1otW" : {...}
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Database Screenshot]

Now, If I want to make previous code work for this case:

```
Elephant ele = datasnapshot.getValue(elephant.class);
```

How do I write my new class for the 'population' node.

In Firebase reference it is said that it returns a `Map<String, Object>` or `List<Object>` java equivalent. But being a beginner in Java I'm stuck with this problem in past 4 days.

I can iterate through the `dataSnapshot.child('population')` and add them in a List of separate '`population`' object. But I've wondered if it can be achieved in this way. Please help me with the code or link me to a example where it was done in one line and automatically. It'll be such a relief.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
class PopulationDetail {
    long count;
    String location;
}

class Elephan {
    ...
    Map<String, PopulationDetail> population;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It worked. :) 
I've been down this road once but somewhere in code I've screwed up and it didn't work.

Comment: please help @Akivamu 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999687/how-to-deserialize-this-hashmap-of-realtime-firebase-database

Answer (score 1):

To convert json into pojo class, try this -

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Thanks for answering. I didn't know this existed. I've pasted my JSON file there and selected JSON at source type. The problem is, along with regular types it created a `-KTcpw_SsMb55qLc6Xme` class and a `-KTcq6YeB3kX3h9F9xPU` class. And that's what I didn't want. So I now I'm learning how to write JSON Schema.

As Firebase don't have native array support how should I write this object to achieve `Map<String, Object>` or `List<Object>` type class?

Comment: In this case you can do as Huy Luu answered.