# how to deserialize this hashmap of realtime firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: data base schema]i have a firebase database schema, in which i wanna to parse and deserialize with

```
Program program = dataSnapshot.getValue(Program.class);
```

the program data class is:

```
public class Program
{

    @SerializedName("has_live_show")
    @Expose
    private Boolean has_live_show;

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("live_url")
    @Expose
    private String live_url;

    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("sponsers")
    @Expose
    private Map<Integer, Sponser> sponsers=new HashMap<>();

    public Program() {
    }

    public Program(Boolean has_live_show, int id, String live_url, String title, Map<Integer, Sponser> sponsers) {
        super();
        this.has_live_show = has_live_show;
        this.id = id;
        this.live_url = live_url;
        this.title = title;
        this.sponsers = sponsers;
    }

    public Boolean getHas_live_show() {
        return has_live_show;
    }

    public void setHas_live_show(Boolean has_live_show) {
        this.has_live_show = has_live_show;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLive_url() {
        return live_url;
    }

    public void setLive_url(String live_url) {
        this.live_url = live_url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Sponser> getSponsersMap() {
        return sponsers;
    }

    public void setSponsersMap(Map<Integer, Sponser> sponsers) {
        this.sponsers = sponsers;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Program{" +
                "hasLiveShow='" + has_live_show + '\'' +
                ", id=" + id +
                ", liveUrl='" + live_url + '\'' +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", sponsers=" + sponsers +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and sponsor data class is

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Sponsor {

    @SerializedName("image")
    @Expose
    private String image;

    @SerializedName("logo")
    @Expose
    private String logo;

    public Sponser() {
    }

    public Sponser(String image, String logo) {
        this.image = image;
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Sponser{" +
                "image='" + image + '\'' +
                ", logo='" + logo + '\'' +
                '}';
    }



}
```

but every time I parse the data snapshot using

```
Program program = dataSnapshot.getValue(Program.class);
```

`program.getSponsersMap()` always equals to null

]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe9AU.png

Answer (score 2):

I use Gson for convert my data, in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

In my code:

```
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(dataSnapshot.getValue());
Program program = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Program.class);
```

and it works for me, firebase use the method does not work in my case

Also in your Program class you must be convert Sponser as List instead of HashMap, if you exports RAW json from Firebase, you must see the object Sponser as List

Comment: Sorry i changed getData() for getValue()

Comment: It is a pleasure to have helped you :). If you wish, do not forget to mark as a solution to help the community

Answer (score 1):

From your JSON the structure is something that Firebase would recognize as an array, so that means that in the Java class it'd be mapped to a `List`.

So:

```
private List<Sponser> sponsers = new List<>();
```

If you really want it to be mapped to a `Map`, make sure the keys are alphanumeric by prefixing them with a short fixed value like `s0`, `s1`, etc.

Comment: this is the part of the solution 

but the full solution worked for me is :


JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(dataSnapshot.getValue());
Program program = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Program.class);